# Replace save file dialog opened by any program by a customized save file dialog

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, customization, savefiledialog

I am working on a Version Control/File Sync System for Windows. It would be great to have a checkbox at the bottom of the classical save file dialog with the option to check/uncheck for my file versioning.

Is it possible to listen for opened save file dialogs by any program (word etc.) and replace/override that dialog with a customized one (with an additional checkbox)?

If the checkbox is checked, another window should pop-up where the user could enter some additional metadata. After that the data is stored in a local database.

I already worked with the approach by dmihailescu (link provided) but it's very complex and I do not know how to modify that example to listen for opened save file dialogs by other programs.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy?msg=4779306#xx4779306xx

Another approach is to use the FileSystemWatcher but that's very expensive to watch the whole system and it's not very comfortable because the user has to be asked for any created file if he/she wants to version control it.

I hope someone could help me to solve that problem or has some additional tips / approaches.

Thank you.

Edit: Use-case

A user has to write a documentation and creates a new word-doc. When he/she clicks the Save as menu entry of word, my customized save file dialog should pop-up with a checkbox at the bottom, if this file should be versioned or not. If the checkbox is "active" a new window should appear where the user could enter additional metadata. After that the data should be stored in local database.

In my case, only the metadata (like the path etc.) should be stored in the database. Let's suppose a user stores the same file in two different directotries (one file is "older" and one file is the current one). If the user opens an older version of this file, my system should recognize that a "newer" one is already stored in another place and synchronize those files.

That should just be a very easy example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two pieces of functionality: save and version-control. Both of the tasks are actually rather complicated. Therefore you shouldn't mix them. You better off using standard Windows API to save file and do not change that. Think about how you'd support several different Windows releases and how painful that would be.

I assume you have your own UI, and do not integrate with, say, Windows Explorer (like Tortoise Svn or Dropbox). In this case you can do version-control magic first and then just save the end file using standard API.

If you do integrate with Windows Explorer, I suggest you to have a look at [Tortoise svn source code](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/checkout).

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I've edited my post and added a use-case. The problem is that I would like to achieve some kind of "automatic" behaviour. If a user creates a doc, my system should recognize that without asking the user for each created doc, if it should be versioned. For usability purposes, I think it's much more comfortable to customize the save file dialog for the whole system (is that possible???) with a checkbox, so that the user could decide whether to version the file or not. Another idea is to add a "versioning"-option to the right click menu.

Comment: How would you recognize if a file was created that the user wants to version control, when I use my own UI without a Windows integration?

Comment: Just personal opinion, try prototyping your ideas, as you seem to have couple of them. In case you want a custom dialog from WinWord, that would require rock-solid knowledge of Win API, COM, word interop, C and C++. I would forget about that. Also from usability perspective, no-one really likes "custom" stuff. Doing additional click is hard, especially if one needs to decide a "version". Version is already availble out of the box in Word, in svn/github and many others. Dropbox does versioning as well. So there seem to be an overlap. What I can personally see is significant overlap

Comment: with mature tools, and man-years worth of work to implement this from scratch. Maybe I just don't get your idea... With regards to you comment "How would you recognize if a file was created that the user wants to version control" - I would write a Windows Service to monitor a specific directory for any change. Now "how to monitor" is rather difficult. I have not got enough exp with that, but there will be posts here regarding File System Watcher and its alternatives.

Comment: I am writing my Master Thesis about that at the moment. What I want to achieve: local Version Control (save file-metadata) + replicate (sync) the DB with a central one, to get access from different devices / collaborate. Interfaces to different systems: USB devices, file system, Cloud-storage (like Dropbox, GoogleDrive: use the API's), eMail-attachments.

Comment: What I want to achieve: that the user always knows, where the current (newest) file is stored and that an old file is synced with the current one (load file from path). Therefore I have to recognize, when a file is created on each system (not only in one specific folder). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do you know if each program uses its own save file dialog? I thought that it's a common (system-wide) dialog that could be modified? If each program has it's own save file dialog, then this approach does not work for me :(

Comment: Any other ideas? Is it possible to listen for open "save file dialog boxes" and replace them by modified ones (system-wide)? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, no other ideas. It's possible to replace system-wide "save file dialog", but that would require a kernel driver. Nearly all antivirus tools will flag this as a virus - rootkit. This is what rootkits do, they replace OS API calls with their own implementation. This would take several man-month for a knowing person. I would recommend to forget about this and redefine your task. But it's just my understanding, I can easily be wrong.